# Oracle - select * where column>5

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I am trying to do a comparison based on a column. Let's say, if column>5.

```
select * where column>5
```

The column contains non digits. I thought Oracle allows one to compare strings (like Java).

Apparently this is not allowed.

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
```

Is there a way to do comparisons with non numeric fields?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to put the 5 in quotes :

```
select * from table where column > '5'
```

Comment: Bear in mind that when comparing strings `'5' > '40'` is *true*.  This is why it is generally a bad idea to store numeric data as a string.

Answer (score 3):

If the column is `varchar2`, then this:

```
select * from some_table where some_column > 5
```

... does an implicit conversion of all the column values to numbers, so you're really doing:

```
select * from some_table where to_number(some_column) > 5
```

It's the `to_number()` that's causing the ORA-01722, even though you can't see it, when it hits a value that is not numeric. The function being called on the column value also stops any index being used (oversimplifying a bit).

You can stop it failing, and let it use the index if there is one, by doing `where some_column > '5'` as other have said, or `where some_column > to_char(5)`. But you need to be careful doing the comparison as it will still be a string comparison, not a numeric one; so `'10'` will **not** be seen as `> '5'`; and your NLS sorting parameters might produce results you aren't expecting. Or more importantly, someone else's NLS parameters - when you put this live for example - might product results you aren't expecting and which don't match the ones you got in your environment. [See the documentation for more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_globalization.htm#i1008368).

You should use `number` columns to hold numeric values, `date` columns to hold dates, etc., and `varchar2` only to hold text values.

Answer (score 3):

To shed a bit more light on why it doesn't work.

When using a number literal `5` instead of a character literal `'5'` Oracle does an implicit data type conversion and tries to convert all values in your table to a number. That's why you get that error.

You should ***never*** rely on implicit data type conversion. That is bound to give you trouble sometime.

Now if you correctly compare a character literal (`'5'`) against a character column, no data type conversion is needed and no error occurs.

However: if you expect Oracle to actually do a numeric comparison then you are mistaken. Character string are based on ASCII values. Therefor the (character) value `'10'` is **lower** than the (character) value `'2`' because the first character `'1'` is ranked lower than `'2'`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `to_char` function

```
select * from table where column > to_char(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the table:

```
select * where FROM tablename column>5
```

But this only works if column is a number. If not, you can't use `>`.

---

To compare strings, you can use `LIKE` or `STRCMP()`, check examples of them [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-comparison-functions.html).

As stated by @Gerrat, you can also use `>` and `<` but the types of both sides must be compatible (number with number or text with text). To find more about it, check [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm).

Be aware that in text comparison it will compare each character individually so '11' will be < that '2'.

Comment: You can use comparisons like '>' with strings in Oracle.  It does what you'd expect.

Comment: @aF., see here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm

Comment: @Gerrat: well not necessarily what you'd expect, because '10' is *smaller* than '2'

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, it might not be what *some* people expect, but I'd wager that `aF` would expect a lexical comparison :)